# Android-x86 MIC and GPS (location services) are not working

Tags: android, gps, microphone, android-x86

I have installed **android-x86** image on a device in which windows was installed. I want to add SpeechRecognizer and get user location functionalities. But mic and GPS are not working.

Can anyone help to solve this problem.

Thanks
Ishan jain

Comment: can you share more details on which version of Android-x86 did you install? Did you install the Google APIs x86 system image?

Comment: I have installed android-x86-4.4-RC1.iso verson. You can see this link http://www.android-x86.org/download